# OpenCMS: Perform different search on command

Tags: lucene, opencms

I have implemented my search features on OpenCMS. Indexed resource comes from many path (e.g. /path/alternative/news and /path/news).
There's a way to perform separated search for every resource or I need two separated index?

Comment: When you go to the OpenCms workplace / Administration / Search Management, and run a query in there on any of the indexes, you can see that you can optionally select a 'Search folder'. So I assume this option/parameter should also be available for your own search (by adding this parameter in the search form in the jsp template). I don't know the exact parameter name yet, but once I know, I will make an answer out of this comment :)

Comment: I resolved by adding: setSearchRoot("/path/news"); and setSearchRoot("/path/alternative/news"); to the search bean.

Comment: Happy to hear. You should make it an answer of the question and close it. I think it's helpful, quite common question I think.

Answer (score 1):

Once indexed the single resources, we can use setSearchRoot() method of the search bean. If I want to perform search inside /path/alternative/news, i set `setSearchRoot("/path/alternative/news")` otherwise, `setSearchRoot("/path/news")`.

Hope that helps.